# How to upload multiple images using Dio and multi_image_picker plugin in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, dart

I want to upload multiple-images using Dio and multi_image_picker plug-in in Flutter.

`List<Asset>` this is the problem because I can't convert from `List<Asset>` to `List<File>` so if you have any solutions help me.

try to use:

1. `multi_image_picker: ^4.6.1`
2. `dio: ^3.0.4`

Thanks

Bona SR.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:merchantside/helper/colorhelper.dart';
import 'package:merchantside/merchantside/login.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:multi_image_picker/multi_image_picker.dart';

class ListImages extends StatefulWidget {
  String errorMessage = "";
  @override
  _ListImagesState createState() => new _ListImagesState();
}

class _ListImagesState extends State<ListImages> {
  List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
  List<File> listImages = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget buildGridView() {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
        Asset asset = images[index];
        return AssetThumb(
          asset: asset,
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
        );
      }),
    );
  }


  void _uploadFiles() async {
    String uid = await FlutterSecureStorage().read(key: "getTocken");
    try {
      var dio = Dio();
      FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
        "pictures[]": images, 
      });
      Response resp = await dio.post(
        mainUrl + 'merchant/upload-galleries',
        data: formData,
        onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
          //
        }, 
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: uid,
          },
        )
      );
      if(resp.statusCode == 200) {
        print("============= Print Resp data: ");
        print(resp.data);
      }

    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future<void> loadAssets() async {
    List<Asset> resultList = List<Asset>();
    try {
      resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
        maxImages: 6,
        enableCamera: true,
        selectedAssets: images,
        cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
        materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
          actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
          actionBarTitle: "Example App",
          allViewTitle: "All Photos",
          useDetailsView: false,
          selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
        ),
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      images = resultList;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: "btn1",
        backgroundColor: ColorHelper.orange,
        child: Icon(Icons.add_photo_alternate),
        onPressed: loadAssets,
      ),
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text('បញ្ជីរូបភាព'),
        backgroundColor: ColorHelper.orange,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          //Error message
          errorMessage != "" ? 
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 10),
            height: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
              color: ColorHelper.red.withOpacity(0.5),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text("$errorMessage", style: TextStyle(color: ColorHelper.swhite, fontSize: 15),),
            ),
          ):
          Container(),

          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 10),
              child: buildGridView(),
            ),
          ),
          SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: ColorHelper.green,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4))
              ),
              height: 50,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  if(images.length > 0) {
                    setState(() {
                      errorMessage = "";
                    });
                    // Call function upload multiple files
                    _uploadFiles();
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      errorMessage = "សូមបញ្ជូលរូបភាព";
                    });
                  } 
                },
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("រួចរាល់", style: TextStyle(color: ColorHelper.swhite, fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,),),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This looks like a reasonable question - but it would probably help if you post the code that you have tried.

Comment: Hello dear, Now i ready Update my source code ...
please help me!
Thanks !

Comment: you can use [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) and get list of files selected directly. It supports multi select and provides file path in response. It will be easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

when you pick images from gallery, called  getFileList() and then called set state,first use global variable of list of file and clear each time this list when you again pick images.

```
  List<File> listFile = List<File>();
  images = resultList;
  _error = error;
   getFileList();

 void getFileList() async{
  listFile.clear();
 for(int i=0; i<images.length; i++){
  var path= await images[i].filePath;
  print(path);
  var file=await getImageFileFromAssets(path);
  print(file);
  listFile.add(file);
}
 setState(() {

 });
}
```

getImageFileFromAsset is used for conver asset to file

```
Future<File> getImageFileFromAsset(String path) async {
final file = File(path);
return file;
```

}

and use listFile in formdata.

Comment: Hello Avinash, when I try to solve that with your solution has this Problem.
var path= await images[i].filePath; undefined filePath.

Comment: images is a List of Asset which return by picker

Comment: its a  method of asset class   /// Requests the original image file path
  Future<String> get filePath {
    return MultiImagePicker.requestFilePath(_identifier);
  }

Comment: check your Asset  class

Comment: you have list of Asset , so you can easily get path from Asset object

Comment: I follow something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59797686/flutter-how-to-convert-filepath-from-content-media-external-images-media-5275

Comment: @Avinash you can't get file path from asset object returned by multi_image_picker

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get a list of byte arrays from a list of `Asset`s:

```
List<Asset> images;
...

List<ByteData> byteDataList = await Future.wait(images.map((Asset image) => image.getByteData()));

List<Uint8List> byteArrayList = byteDataList.map((ByteData byteData) {
  ByteBuffer byteBuffer = byteData.buffer;
  return byteBuffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteBuffer.lengthInBytes);
}).toList();
```

Now you can use the list of byte arrays to build a payload using your network client of choice. For those not using 3rd party networking clients, that would be a `MultipartRequest` with multiple `MultipartFile.fromBytes`.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need to convert Asset into File**, You can send is as a byte array.

Only need to create the Multipart object of each image.

You can get the byte array from the Assets

```
 ByteData byteData = await asset.getByteData();
  List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
```

then it can pass through **MultipartFile.fromBytes()** method.

so it will look like,

```
  String url = "upload/url";

          List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
          List<MultipartFile> multipartImageList = new List<MultipartFile>();
          if (null != images) {
            for (Asset asset in images) {
              ByteData byteData = await asset.getByteData();
              List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
              MultipartFile multipartFile = new MultipartFile.fromBytes(
                imageData,
                filename: 'load_image',
                contentType: MediaType("image", "jpg"),
              );
              multipartImageList.add(multipartFile);
            }

            FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
              "multipartFiles": multipartImageList,
              "userId": '1'
            });

            Dio dio = new Dio();
            var response = await dio.post(url, data: formData);
          }
```

[FYI](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/330)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) and get list of files selected directly. It supports multi select and provides file path in response. It will be easiest way.

```
List<File> files = await FilePicker.getMultiFilePath(
          type: FileType.IMAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used dio and multi_image plugin in my app and its working properly. What am doing is giving my code snippets here. You can say this is working version and should work in any app.

bloc class

```
final imageController = BehaviorSubject<List<Asset>>();
StreamSink<List<Asset>> get sinkImages =>
  imageController.sink;
Stream<List<Asset>> get getImages => imageController.stream;

Future<void> loadImages(imageCount) async {
List<Asset> imageList = List<Asset>();
String error = 'No Error Dectected';

try {
  imageList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
    maxImages: imageCount,
    enableCamera: true,
    cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(
      takePhotoIcon: "chat",
    ),
    materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
      actionBarColor: "#0A73B1",
      statusBarColor: "#0A73B1",
      actionBarTitle: "Select Image",
      allViewTitle: "All Photos",
      useDetailsView: false,
      selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
    ),
  );
} on Exception catch (e) {
  error = e.toString();
  print(error);
}

_error = error;
imageController.add(imageList);
}
```

//call this method when you initiating api call

```
Future<GenericResponse> uploadImageRequest() async {
      RequestModel reqModel = RequestModel(
                     uploadImageList: getImages);

      final SharedPref prefs = SharedPref();
      String token = await prefs.readString(accessToken);

      GenericResponse response = await _application.repository
          .uploadRequest(reqModel: reqModel, accessToken: token);

      return response;
    }
```

So you already got your image list by this. And also set these list into your request model class. Now lets send these image as multipart using dio.

API class method

//call from repository class

```
Future<GenericResponse> uploadRequest(
  {RequestModel reqModel, String accessToken}) async {
return await _apiProvider.uploadRequest(
    reqModel: reqModel, accessToken: accessToken);
}
```

//upload image api request

```
Future<ResponseModel> uploadRequest(
  {RequestModel requestModel, String accessToken}) async {

List<MultipartFile> imageList = [];

imageList = await getMultiPartImages(requestModel.imageList);

FormData formData = FormData.fromMap(RequestModel(
        uploadImageList: imageList,
    .toJson());

try {
  Response response = await getDio().post(
    'api/endpoint',
    options: Options(headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
    }),
    data: formData,
  );
  return ResponseModel.fromJson(response.data);
} catch (error, stacktrace) {
  debugPrint("Exception occured: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace");
  return ResponseModel.withError(handleError(error));
 }
}
```

// podo model class

```
class RequestModel {
 var uploadImageList;

 RequestModel(
  {this.uploadImageList});

 RequestModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  uploadImageList = json['image_list'];
 }

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
 final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
 data['image_list'] = this.uploadImageList;
 return data;
}

@override
String toString() {
  return toJson().toString();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and effective:

```
Map<String, dynamic> params = Map();
params['images'] = null;
Map<String, dynamic> headers = {
  HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'multipart/form-data',
};
List<MultipartFile> multipart = List<MultipartFile>();

//listImage is your list assets.
for (int i = 0; i < listImage.length; i++) {
  ByteData byteData = await listImage[i].getByteData();
  List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  print("name: ${listImage[i].name}");
  String fileName = "${listImage[i].name}";
  multipart.add(MultipartFile.fromBytes(imageData, filename: fileName, contentType: MediaType("image", "jpg"),));
}
if (multipart.isNotEmpty){
  params['images'] = multipart;
}

FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple try this way,

```
String url1 =
    "Enter Your Url Here";

FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
  "equipment_id": equipmentid,
  "equipcount": equipcount,
  'equipImage': equipmentimages.map((item) => MultipartFile.fromFileSync(item.path,
          filename: item.path.split('/').last))
      .toList(),
  "equipNotes": equipmentnotes,
  "disposable_id": disposableid,
  "disposCount": disposablecount,
  "disposImage": disposableimages?.map((item) => MultipartFile.fromFileSync(item.path,
          filename: item.path.split('/').last))
      .toList(),
  "disposNotes": disposablenotes,
  "image": jobimage.map((item) => MultipartFile.fromFileSync(item.path,
          filename: item.path.split('/').last))
      .toList(),
  "note": jobnotes,
});

try {
  final response = await dio.put(url1, data: data);
  print(response.toString());
  return response.data["message"];
} on DioError catch (e) {
  print(e);
  throw e.response!.data['message'];
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
  throw e.toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
   FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'id': 'ZE8980',
      'name': 'myTitle',
      'age':'22',
      'order_images': [
        for (var file in images)

         // ....SPRED images

        ...{
          await MultipartFile.fromFile(getImage(file).imageFile.path,
              filename: getImage(file).imageFile.path.split('/').last)
        }.toList()
      ]
    });
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    var response = await dio.post(url, data: formData);
```