# Flutter how to Convert filePath from content://media/external/images/media/5275 to /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_00124.jpg

Tags: flutter, mobile

I have URI LIKE below

```
content://media/external/images/media/5275
```

but I want convert it to Like format below:

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_00124.jpg
```

Anyone who can help me!

Sreng Bona

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723992/flutter-how-to-convert-uri-to-file 
please refer this link.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var path = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath("content://media/external/images/media/5275");
```

Add this `flutter_absolute_path: ^1.0.6` to your file: `pubspec.yaml`

It will be working as Well.

Bona SR.

Answer (score 2):

I had to search a lot, but I found a very useful solution to save the image in the cell phone's photo gallery and get the absolute path to use it the way you want.
For this example I used a result obtained from saving an image in the photo gallery, however it could also work to read other files, obviously making the changes that you see necessary, I hope it will help you
[uri_to_file](https://pub.dev/packages/uri_to_file)
[image_gallery_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver)

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:uri_to_file/uri_to_file.dart';

Future<File> saveImage(File image, String identifier) async {
try {
    var result = await 
    ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(image.readAsBytesSync(),
     quality: 60, name: identifier + 
    "-${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}");
    print(result);
    File file = await toFile(Uri.parse(result['filePath']));
    print(file);
    return file;
   } catch (e) {
     print(e);
    return new File('assets/img/default-img.jpg');
  }
}
// example
saveImage(File("path/image.jpg"),"img-test");
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly !