# How to Pick Multiple Image And Upload it via RestAPI Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to pick multiple images from gallery and upload them via Flutter Dio Package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pick images from the library use a package from pub.dev. For example [multi_image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker) for example.

The question of uploading multiple images to Dio [is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59780379/how-to-upload-multiple-images-using-dio-and-multi-image-picker-plugin-in-flutter). But here is the suggested solution in the linked article:

```
Future<Response<dynamic>> uploadImages(List<Asset> images, String url) async {
  List<MultipartFile> multipartImageList = new List<MultipartFile>();

  for (Asset asset in images) {
    ByteData byteData = await asset.getByteData();
    List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    MultipartFile multipartFile = new MultipartFile.fromBytes(
      imageData,
      filename: 'load_image',
      contentType: MediaType("image", "jpg"),
    );
    multipartImageList.add(multipartFile);
  }

  FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
    "multipartFiles": multipartImageList,
    "userId": '1'
  });

  Dio dio = new Dio();
  var response = await dio.post(url, data: formData);
  return response;
}
```

Comment: I want to upload multiple images...... not single image